# Ruby date and time in database check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new in Ruby. I have form which creates new appointment (I save there `doctor_id`, `patient_id`, `date`, `time`) I have also schedules in database (`doctor_id` in schedule is `FK`, there are `dayofweek`, `starttime`, `endtime`) and now I want to check if doctor is available in chosen day and time and if there are no appointment with this date and time. If I can't add and error message.

Translate for your better understanding:

```
-dzien_tygodnia - day_of_the_week;
-data_wizyty - visit_date;
-godzina_wizyty - visit_time;
-poczatek_pracy - start_working;
-koniec_pracy - end_working.
```

My `_form.html.erb`:

```
    <%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>
  <% if @appointment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@appointment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this appointment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @appointment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :data_wizyty %><br />
  <%=
    options = { start_year: 2.year.from_now.year,
                end_year: 2013,
                include_blank: true,
                default: nil }
    f.date_select :data_wizyty, options
  %>
  <!--<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' :data_wizyty > -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :godzina_wizyty %><br />
    <%= f.time_select :godzina_wizyty %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :doctor_id, :value => Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, :value => Patient.find(session[:current_patient_id]).id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Utworz wizyte" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`appointment.rb`:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :doctor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:data_wizyty, :godzina_wizyty], message: 'Ten termin jest juz zajety!' }
  validate :doctor_is_scheduled

  attr_accessible :data_wizyty, :doctor_id, :godzina_wizyty, :notatka, :objawy_choroby, :patient_id



    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :doctor
    belongs_to :schedule
    belongs_to :refferal

    has_many :employees

  def doctor_is_scheduled
    if Schedule.where(doctor: doctor, dzien_tygodnia: data_wizyty.wday)
               .where('poczatek_pracy < ? and koniec_pracy > ?', godzina_wizyty, godzina_wizyty).empty?
      self.errors.add(:doctor, message: 'nie pracuje w tym terminie!')
    end
  end


end
```

Could you tell me which files should be included?

Comment: When checking that there isn't an appointment at that date and time, will that be an appointment with the current doctor, or an appointment with any doctor?

Comment: I.E., can multiple doctors have an appointment at the same time?

Comment: Yes, they can, I just have to add in which days and hours easch of them works :)

Comment: Ok perfect. In that case, I believe that my solution should work for you.

Comment: But I am really, really new in this and I think it will be too hard to do for me :(

Comment: Check please my edited question and help me if you can what to do :)

Comment: I saw now that I have error undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class when open appointment/new

Comment: It said that error is in this line <%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %> in _form51.html.erb

Comment: And another one before D:/Studia/Bazy Danych/Projekt/Implementacja/ZOZ/app/models/appointment.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC

Comment: Ok, I have changed this line to   validates :doctor, uniqueness: { scope: [:data_wizyty, :godzina_wizyty], message: 'Ten termin jest juz zajety!' } but now I get undefined method `text?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ok it looks like you fixed the `unexpected '}'` and `undefined method 'text?'` errors, but are you still getting `undefined method 'model_name`? Are there any other errors you're getting?

Comment: now I download updated project from repository and added my files and I have lots of problems :(

Comment: In order for me to help you, you'll need to be much more specific than that. Are any of them related to the addition of the validation methods that I posted? If so, please add them as an update to your question.

Comment: Any luck with resolving errors?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for here are [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). Give that Rails Guide a read, because it'll be incredibly helpful for you. As for your question, you should be able use the following:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :doctor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:date, :time], 'already has an appointment at that time' }
  validate :doctor_is_scheduled

  def doctor_is_scheduled
    if Schedule.where(doctor: doctor, dayofweek: date.wday)
               .where('starttime < ? and endtime > ?', time, time).empty?
      self.errors.add(:doctor, 'is not scheduled to be working at that time')
    end
  end
end
```

The first line (`validates :doctor_id, uniqueness:`) checks that for the given date and time, the doctor is unique, i.e. the doctor won't be double-booked. The `doctor_is_scheduled` method checks to see for the given doctor and day of the week, the doctor has a shift (between `starttime` and `endtime`) scheduled.